# What does "set keymap vi" actually do?

Tags: readline, vi-mode

In an effort to vim-theme Readline, I see there are two

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi
```

I believe I understand what `editing-mode vi` does providing different VIM keymaps to edit, and insert text and such.

What does the `set keymap vi` do juxtaposed to `set editing-mode vi`? What extra do I get out of it?

---

**There are a lot of really bad overly complex answers. Things I don't care about emacs (in any fashion), commands that are undocumented but otherwise the same as documented commands, what my defaults are (I'm obviously trying to change them).**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is equivalent to, and alias for, `set keymap vi-command` and is used to begin defining custom keybinds when in vi-command mode.

So, in your `~/.inputrc` you could use it like so:

```
set keymap vi-command
# or set keymap vi (or, for that matter: set keymap vi-move)
# these are for vi-command mode
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

The other valid option (after setting `editing-mode` to `vi`) is `keymap vi-insert` for the remaining modal offering.

Comment: So basically the "keymap" is simply the mode of vim, there are two to choose from one of those modes is for command mode, and the other for insert mode.

Comment: Essentially. It is just defining for readline what modes to apply specific bindings to.

Answer (score 1):

> What does “set keymap vi” actually do?

Mark the point that start a list of key definitions that apply only to the keymap named.

The keymap names can be

> The set of legal keymap names is emacs, emacs-standard, emacs-meta, emacs-ctlx, vi, vi-move, vi-command, and vi-insert. vi is equivalent to vi-command; emacs is  equivalent to emacs-standard.

The modes vi, vi-move and vi-command seem to be equivalent names for the same.

So, from the point in `.inputrc` file that a keymap appear until a different keymap gets activated (or the mode is changed (vi and emacs)) the key settings apply the the keymap named in the starting keymap command.